# How to get and install licensed windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista

HI! I had my laptop reformatted; I have a licensed windows vista before; I didnt realize that the tech has installed a fake windows 7..so i want to change into a licensed one, how do i go about it? can i just buy online then install it? can i install it alone or do i need tech assistance? thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I wouldn't pay that tech again.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing you can do is buy a upgrade edition of Windows 7 then simply install it from scratch. During activation, if it fails, use the phone method and if it fails, ring the free phone number and explain that it is a laptop with a fully licensed copy of Windows Vista.

Comment: So its only the upgrade version? no need to buy the full version? i was thinking since it was not a genuine windows 7 installed, i have to get the full version.

Comment: You may have less problems with the full version, however if you forget the fact you have a dodgy copy of 7, you do have a fully licensed copy of Vista which qualifies you for the upgrade. You never know what you get with a dodgy copy and there could be hidden *surprises* so during the install, I would format the drive and get rid of every trace of it.

Answer (score 0):

Several suggestions:

If you are a student, you can try and get the student copy of Win7 at a reduced price.  I believe it is upgrade but should work.  Check with your college.  You can also get Office 2007 at a super reduced price.

You can possibly get an OEM version.  These are white box versions at a reduced price but are not supported directly by Microsoft.  Sold through places like Newegg.

You can also try and report your copy as a pirate version.  Microsoft USED TO offer to sell you a legitimate copy of an OS at a reduced price.  I don't know if this is the case with Win 7.

Regardless, if you aren't comfortable, have someone you trust install the OS for you.